# Access JSONObject field value in lambda expression

Tags: java, json, lambda, functional-programming

I am pretty new to Java and I am quite found of *fonctional programming*. Here I am trying to write the most concise factory method to create a `List<Manager>` based on a `JSONArray` retrieved from an API. Here is a simplified version of what I have in mind

```java
public List<Manager> getManagers(HashMap parameters) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    JSONArray records = (JSONArray) api.getData("Manager", parameters).get("records");
    records.forEach(x -> new Manager(x.get("FirstName"),x.get("LastName")))
```

and how I would do it in **python** (I am highly biased)

```py
manager_list = list(map(lambda x: Manager(x["FirstName"],x["LastName"]),records))
```

I am experiencing **two issues**.

1. access JSONObject fields inside the **lambda expression**

Despite x being a `JSONObject`

```java
records.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getClass()));
class org.json.JSONObject
```

`x.get("FirstName")` does not work in the lambda. Is it because `.get()` is an **instance method** or am I missing something else?

2. easily append `Managers` to a list

This does not work

```java
List managers = records.forEach(x -> new Manager(x.get("FirstName"),x.get("LastName")))
```

because `forEach` returns `void`. Does `forEach` have a cousin who could return any kind of `Interable` or `Collection` ?

Since I am new to java, I both interested in implementations for my actual problem and more general discussions on functional programming in modern java

Comment: Are you sure that `org.json.JSONObject` is `Iterable`?

Comment: `JSONObject`, dunno. `JSONArray` is iterable, for sure. I had no trouble displaying individual json objects using `System.out.println(x)`

Comment: `x.get('FirstName')` you are using single quotes here, just wondering how the code is compiling.

Comment: @GyowannyPessattoQueiroz my bad. Correcting

Comment: Just so we don't overlook the obvious, your correction to `x.get('FirstName')` changed the property name as well as the quotes. It is now `x.get("FistName")`. Another typo?

Comment: @TheHeadRush yeah, I am the distracted type

Comment: As an aside, you can convert directly from the api call:  `List<Manager> managers = api.getData("Manager", parameters).get("records").stream(Collectors.toMap(j -> this::myMapFn)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```java
public List<Manager> getManagers(HashMap parameters) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
    JSONArray records = (JSONArray) api.getData("Employee", parameters).get("records");

    List<Manager> managers = new ArrayList<>();
    records.forEach(jsonRecord -> {
        JSONObject record = (JSONObject) jsonRecord;
        managers.add(new Manager(record.getString("FirstName"), record.getString("LastName")));
    });

    return managers;
    }
```

You may have to cast each item into a `JSONObject` in order to access the properties.

Comment: Works like a charm and pretty concice. I love it. May I slightly edit your answer before accepting it (just to have the final `List<Manager>` and the complete implementation)? Noobs like me enjoy exhaustive solutions

Comment: I'm glad it worked, sure go ahead and edit!